# How to update my mat-tree without it rerendering?

Tags: angular, asynchronous, angular-material, treeview

My mat tree redraws initializes itself on datasource data change using a BehaviorSubject.

I am using an observable that i update form time to time in order to update the tree data generated by a FlatTreeControl.

The code is pretty basic and easy to understand so I don't see the issue.

I tried using a simplified version of the angular flat tree example on stackBlitz:
https://stackblitz.com/angular/rlqvokgplrko?file=app%2Ftree-checklist-example.ts

Here is my version:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/create-iq2meg

What i expect is that as in the official mat-tree example, the data is updated dynamically WITHOUT having to redraw the entire tree and having it collapse on me each time.

Answer (score 13):

We may use a workaround for this as mentioned in [GitHub by @danielkuhlwein](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/11984#issuecomment-519972431)

Save expanded nodes to a list before doing any re-rendering:

```js
saveExpandedNodes() {
    this.expandedNodes = new Array<BulletFlatNode>();
    this.treeControl.dataNodes.forEach(node => {
        if (node.expandable && this.treeControl.isExpanded(node)) {
            this.expandedNodes.push(node);
        }
    });
}
```

And then restore the expanded nodes after doing the re-rendering:

```js
restoreExpandedNodes() {
    this.expandedNodes.forEach(node => {
        this.treeControl.expand(this.treeControl.dataNodes.find(n => n.id === node.id));
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  transformer = (node: TodoItemNode, level: number) => {
    const existingNode = this.nestedNodeMap.get(node);
    const flatNode =
      existingNode && existingNode.item === node.item
        ? existingNode
        : new TodoItemFlatNode();
    flatNode.item = node.item;
    flatNode.level = level;
    flatNode.expandable = !!node.children;
    this.flatNodeMap.set(flatNode, node);
    this.nestedNodeMap.set(node, flatNode);
    return flatNode;
  };
```

The above method is different in both examples

https://stackblitz.com/angular/rlqvokgplrko?file=app%2Ftree-checklist-example.ts

https://stackblitz.com/edit/create-iq2meg

This code will help to remember the node state while re-rendering,
it checks for existing node data else it will create new nodes

Here is my example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/create-5dss9p?file=app/mat-tree/mat-tree/mat-tree.component.html